# I need to post a file from angular. My backend is .net core web api.

Tags: .net, angular6

I need to post a file from angular. My backend is .net core web api. I have tried writing a few lines of code but the problem is that API is not being hit. I have searched a lot on the internet but I wasn't able to find anything similar (I am a newbie and have an experience of 1 month, kindly help! ).

**Angular6**

postResume is a method in my service (named 'dataService').

```
postResume(resume):Observable<any>{
debugger;
var model={
  "resume":resume
}return this.http.post('http://localhost:54770/api/candidates/PostResume',model);}
```

The above method 'postResume()' is being triggered by another function 'register()' that is being called when i hit a button on my html page.

register(){

```
this.dataService.postResume(this.dataService.getResume()).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);
});
this.dataService.registerCandidate(this.data).subscribe(res=>{  
},err=>{
  if(err.error.text=="Register Successful")
  {
  this.toastr.success("Candidate Registered Successfully", 'Candidate Register')
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
  if(err.error.text =="Email already exist") 
  {
  this.toastr.error("Email Already Exists!! Please enter different email to register",'Candidate Register')
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
});
```

}

**.net web api**

[HttpPost("[action]")]

```
    public IActionResult PostResume([FromBody] SomeModel model)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            model.Resume.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        return Ok("File Saved");
    }
```

Model consists of -

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public IFormFile Resume { get; set; }
}
```

Here in the given API Candidates is the controller name and PostResume is the name of the method.

Comment: PS- I am getting 400 (Bad Request) when i try to hit the api

Comment: If u take a simple input element, does it work? Also post the IFormFile details

Comment: I am trying to upload a doc/pdf file so i took IFormFile as file type